# extendable wxwidgets

Tags: python, wxpython

I was windering if it is possible to create an extendable layout. This would be: a program or suite where you wouldn't need to change the basic sourcecode to add buttons or text-fields, but rather add them in a file of your own.

Comment: I recommend the approach that dav1d recommended. XRC is probably the easiest way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your GUI from XML-Resources:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/11/wxpython-an-introduction-to-xrc/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/XRCTutorial
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingXmlResources

You could e.g. use [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) to generate these XML files.